# Need to display list of product categories

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I'm exploring **Nwazet.Commerce** module and I've managed to replicate most of what http://nwazet.com/ does ... However I'm struggling with projection widget that displays product categorization (on nwazet.com page one to the right that has Automation, Cables & Connections, ...).

I assume these are terms for a taxonomy? How should I set projection query to get this list of terms from a single taxonomy? When I tried "**Content with type CategoryTerm**" it lists not just terms but also products that have them.

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it exactly right: the categories are taxonomy terms. The problem is very likely that you are displaying the terms in the projection query layout with the full detail view, where the term will display the list of items under itself. Instead, you could use a summary or a custom display type in your layout, and customize the template alternate for that display type. Alternatively, and this is how the site is set-up, you can switch to property mode for the layout and just keep it to a simple display text property with "link to the item" checked.

Some additional info: for perf, I add an eager fetch filter on Autoroute and Title part records.